# Behind the scene of nested operation in Python

Tags: python, python-internals

We know that for an operation, we can write a code as:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = 2
c = sum(a)
result = c**b
```

or its possible to calculate `result` in one line as:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = 2
result = sum(a)**b
```

in the first case, `sum(a)` is calculated, placed in the memory with a variable name `c` and retrieved for calculating `result`. In the latter case, does the python interpreter create a temporary variable for `sum(a)` or something else is happening behind the scene?

Comment: when calling sum(a) there is a default value which is 0 will be defined by the sum function so in reality you are calling sum(a,0), so python will place 0 in memory and add to it every item in a. hope it helps

Comment: @basilisk. Thank you for your comment. I indeed meant how and where `sum(a)` is stored in the latter case.

Answer (score 3):

In the second case, Python interpreter (which is stack based) stores the result of `sum` in the stack, and then do the power operation after loading the value of name `b`.

You can check the bytecodes to see exactly how it's done:

```
In [182]: def one(): 
     ...:     a = [1, 2, 3] 
     ...:     b = 2 
     ...:     c = sum(a) 
     ...:     return c**b 
     ...:

In [183]: def two(): 
     ...:     a = [1, 2, 3] 
     ...:     b = 2 
     ...:     return sum(a)**b 
     ...:

In [184]: dis.dis(one)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              6 BUILD_LIST               3
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          10 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  4          14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             20 STORE_FAST               2 (c)

  5          22 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
             24 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             26 BINARY_POWER
             28 RETURN_VALUE

In [185]: dis.dis(two)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              6 BUILD_LIST               3
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          10 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  4          14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             20 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             22 BINARY_POWER
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

Specifically see the following two bytecodes are missing on `two`:

```
             20 STORE_FAST               2 (c)

  5          22 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
```

As the storing-loading of the local variable `c` is not needed in the second case, it would also be faster than the first one.

Comment: @heemayl. Thank you. So if there are several nested operations in one line, how the interpreter knows where they are stored?

Comment: @Khani: When the Python code is being turned into bytecode, the compiler keeps track of what will be on the stack at any given time and makes sure each operation sees the values it expects, in the right order.